# What is Plan hash value in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, performance, optimization

What is Plan hash value in Oracle ? Does this imply anything related to time of execution of a query ? How do I find execution time of a query in Oracle ?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 views that show SQL statements that ran in your SGA.

```
V$SQL shows stats and is updated every 5 seconds.
V$SQLAREA shows parsed statements in memory, ready to execute.
V$SQLSTATS has greater retention than V$SQL.
```

So if you look in V$SQL you will see every statement has a unique SQL ID.  When the statement is parsed, oracle generates an explain plan for the SQL and then associates that plan with a hash value which is a unique value for that plan.  Certain factors can cause the plan to change, making it execute better or worse.  Then you will get a new plan and a new hash value for that plan.

To see the history of this, look at view `DBA_HIST_SQL_PLAN`.

There is a lot more theory around explain plans and how to optimize SQL statements, and how to give them profiles and baselines, but I hope this gives you an idea of the basics.